# neat IF condtion implementation in a scripting language

Tags: c#, method-chaining, scripting-language

I have a little helper class that generates a script, used later in my code, namely :

```
public class ScriptBuilder
{
    public string Script { get; set; }
    public ScriptBuilder NewLine(uint numberOfLines = 1)
    {
        if (numberOfLines == 0)
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfLines; ++i)
            {
                Script += Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
    public ScriptBuilder WriteLine(string str = "")
    {
        if (str != "")
        {
            Script += str;
            NewLine();
        }
        return this;
    }
    public ScriptBuilder(string line = "")
    {
        Script = line;
        if (line != "")
        {
            NewLine();
        }
    }
    public ScriptBuilder setLong(string longName, long x)
    {
        WriteLine("int " + longName + " " + x.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        return this;
    }

    // + other set functions with different parameters/numbers of parameters
}

// ScriptBuilder is used like this :

ScriptBuilder scriptStringBuilder = new ScriptBuilder();
scriptStringBuilder
    .WriteLine($"/!HEADSTART")
    .WriteLine($"/! TYPE = {scriptType}")
    .WriteLine($"/! NAME = {name}")
    .WriteLine($"/! DESCRIPTION  = {description}")
    .WriteLine($"/!HEADEND")
    /* the header is done now */
    .NewLine(2);
```

It is pretty basic method chaining. I would like to implement `IF` and `IF ELSE IF ELSE` in this scripting language, but I don't see a really neat way for doing it.

For the `IF` I came up with the member function :

```
public ScriptBuilder IF(bool condition, ScriptBuilder res)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

that can be used as :

```
ScriptBuilder.IF(condition,
    scriptStringBuilder
        .setThis(...)
        .setThat(...)
    ;
    )
```

but I am not satisfied because

- `scriptStringBuilder.setThis(...).setThat(...);` would alread have taken effect
- I have to write `scriptStringBuilder` to use it. No pertinent idea of the `IF ELSE IF ELSE` though.

I could use delegates perhaps, like :

```
public delegate ScriptBuilder ScriptBuilderFunction(params object[] Parameters);
public ScriptBuilder IF(bool condition, ScriptBuilderFunction func)
{
    // ...
}
```

but I don't even see how to implement that ...

Ideally, I would like to write :

```
scriptStringBuilder.
    .setThis(...)
    .setThat(...)
    .IF(condition)
    .THEN()
        .setThis(...)
        .doThat(...)
    .ELSEIF(othercondition)
        .makeThis(...)
        .doThat(...)
    .ENDIF()
    .setThatNow(...)
    ;
```

Comment: I hope `MaxStringBuilder` is an expression of some sort, otherwise the parameter to that `IF` method has already been evaluated, any side effects of calling `.setThis` and so on will already have taken effect.

Comment: It was a typo, sorry, it is `ScriptBuilder`

Comment: A it is flawed anyway per your right remark, yes

Comment: You could try IF(condition, then_expression, else_expression).

Comment: @AndreiM If I understand right, I don't see how this changes the evaluation question pointed by Lasse.

Comment: it's a simplification of FCin's answer (and how Excel macros are working, btw). Instead of having different function calls, you pass the condition, the if and the else branches to the IF function, which is calling one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *very* rough sketch of how you could implement this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var number = 999;

        ScriptBuilder scriptStringBuilder = new ScriptBuilder();
        var text = scriptStringBuilder
            .WriteLine($"/!HEADSTART")
            .WriteLine($"/! TYPE = abc")
            .WriteLine($"/! NAME = name")
            .WriteLine($"/!HEADEND")
            .NewLine(2)
            .IfCondition(number != 999, ifCondition => {
                ifCondition.NewLine(1);
                ifCondition.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
            }, elseCondition => {
                elseCondition.NewLine(1);
                elseCondition.WriteLine("FAIL");
            }, 
            elseIf1 => elseIf1.ElseIfCondition(number > 1, h1 => h1.WriteLine("NUMBER IS BIGGER THAN 1")),
            elseIf2 => elseIf2.ElseIfCondition(number > 2, h2 => h2.WriteLine("NUMBER IS BIGGER THAN 2")))
            .Build();

        Console.WriteLine(text);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ScriptBuilder : IElseIfConditionable
{
    private string _script;

    public ScriptBuilder NewLine(uint numberOfLines = 1)
    {
        if (numberOfLines == 0)
        {
            return this;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfLines; ++i)
            {
                _script += Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
    public ScriptBuilder WriteLine(string str = "")
    {
        if (str != "")
        {
            _script += str;
            NewLine();
        }
        return this;
    }
    public ScriptBuilder(string line = "")
    {
        _script = line;
        if (line != "")
        {
            NewLine();
        }
    }
    public ScriptBuilder SetLong(string longName, long x)
    {
        WriteLine("int " + longName + " " + x.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        return this;
    }

    public string Build()
    {
        return _script;
    }

    public ScriptBuilder IfCondition(bool condition, Action<ScriptBuilder> trueCondition, Action<ScriptBuilder> falseCondition, params Func<IElseIfConditionable, Tuple<ScriptBuilder, bool>>[] elseIfs)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            trueCondition(this);
            return this;
        }

        foreach (var elseIf in elseIfs)
        {
            if (elseIf(this).Item2)
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

        if (!condition)
        {
            falseCondition(this);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Tuple<ScriptBuilder, bool> ElseIfCondition(bool condition, Action<ScriptBuilder> trueCondition)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            trueCondition(this);
        }

        return Tuple.Create(this, condition);
    }
}

public interface IElseIfConditionable
{
    Tuple<ScriptBuilder, bool> ElseIfCondition(bool condition, Action<ScriptBuilder> trueCondition);
}
```

This is equivalent of:

```
var s = new ScriptBuilder();
if (number != 999)
{
    s.NewLine(1);
    s.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
}
else if (number > 1)
{
    s.WriteLine("NUMBER IS BIGGER THAN 1");
}
else if (number > 2)
{
    s.WriteLine("NUMBER IS BIGGER THAN 2");
}
else
{
     s.NewLine(1);
     s.WriteLine("FAIL");
}
```

Comment: That seems to work ! How would you do for a switch case statement ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj if/elseif/else is the same as switch statement (I don't care if it doesn't use hashes internally), so there is no reason to implement it separately.

Comment: I don't understand why you couldn't use only param arrays ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj param array `IElseIfConditionable, Tuple<ScriptBuilder, bool>`? If you replace `trueCondition` and `falseCondition` with param array then you would have to write `.IfCondition(s => s.ElseIfCondition(...))` and it would still work, but it doesn't look as nice. Also, here you make sure that if/else is always specified and with params you could end up with an empty `IfCondition`. As I wrote, this is only a very rough sketch. Play with it yourself and have fun :)